# Are there guidelines for when a directive should have its own controller

Tags: angularjs

I have written a couple of directives now. One or two of them used their own controller. I have been looking at how some of angular's own directives work as well as some of the angular UI bootstrap directives work.

They also some times use controllers. For the most part it seems like controllers just add a nice way of wrapping code and keeping it more modular. I am sure there must be some more sound advice on when exactly your directive should gets its own controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-custom-directives_demo_creating-directives-that-communicate):

> ... readers may be wondering what the difference is between link and controller. The basic difference is that controller can expose an API, and link functions can interact with controllers using require.

If you have two or more directives that need to share data between them, it's recommendable to define a controller in one directive and then require it in another:

```
.directive('myFirstDirective', function(){
    return {
        //...
        controller: function(){
            this.doSomething = function(){...};
            return;
        }
        //...
    };
})
.directive('mySecondDirective', function(){
    return {
        require: 'myFirstDirective',
        //link's fourth param is the required controller object.
        link: function($scope, $iElement, $iAtrrs, requiredController){
            $iElement.on('click', function(){ 
                requiredController.doSomething();
                return;
            });
            return;
        }
     };
});
```

If directives are independent from each other, then it's fine to only have link functions.